# How to use Chrome Profile in Selenium Webdriver Python 3

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-profile

So whenever I try to use my Chrome settings (the settings I use in the default browser) by adding

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\... (my webdriver path)")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="myPath", options=options)
```

it shows me the error code

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes n 16-17: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

in my bash. I don't know what that means and I'd be happy for any kind of help I can get. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As per your question and your *code trials* if you want to open a *Chrome Browsing Session* here are the following options:

- To use the default *Chrome Profile*:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
  ```
- Note: Your *default chrome profile* would contain a lot of bookmarks, extensions, theme, cookies etc. *Selenium* may fail to load it. So as per the best practices create a new *chrome profile* for your *@Test* and store/save/configure within the profile the required data.
- To use the customized *Chrome Profile*:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
  ```
- Here you will find a detailed discussion on [How to open a Chrome Profile through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python)

Comment: I am able to load default profile. But once i add Profile 2 (which i have created and now present inside the user data folder) it will not load profile

Comment: I couldn't get the second profile to work this way, had to copy it to a different location as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66706022/10106315

Answer (score 43):

The accepted answer is wrong. This is the official and correct way to do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\path\to\chrome\user\data") #e.g. C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=YourProfileDir') #e.g. Profile 3
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
```

To find the profile folder on Windows right-click the desktop shortcut of the Chrome profile you want to use and go to properties -> shortcut and you will find it in the "target" text box.

Comment: Should I bother saving cookies (e.g. via pickle module) or does loading a profile imply saving them under the hood?

Comment: You are very right. Thank you very much
Could I run the webdriver with a profile even if the main google chrom is running? Beacuse I am getting an error "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir"

Answer (score 31):

To get the path, follow the steps below.

In the search bar type the following and press enter

[image]

This will then show all the metadata. There find the path to the profile

[image]

Answer (score 9):

None of the given answers were working for me so I researched a bit and now the working code is for is this one. I copied the user dir folder from Profile Path from chrome://version/ and made another argument for the profile as shown below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\gupta\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
options.add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 1')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Comment: Yes, this one work!

Answer (score 3):

This is how I managed to use EXISTING CHROME PROFILE in **php selenium webdriver**.
Profile 6 is NOT my default profile. I dont know how to run default profile. It is IMPORTANT not to add -- before chrome option arguments! All other variants of options didnt work!

```
<?php
//...
$chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
$chromeOptions->addArguments([
    'user-data-dir=C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data',
    'profile-directory=Profile 6'
]);

$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $chromeOptions);
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 100000, 100000);
```

To get name of your chrome profile, go to chrome://settings/manageProfile, click on profile icon, click "Show profile shortcut on my desktop". After that right click on desktop profile icon and go to properties, here you will see something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory=**"Profile 6"**.

Also I recommend you to close all chrome instances before running this code. Also maybe you need to TURN OFF chrome settings > advanced > system > "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed".

Answer (score 2):

1. Get profile **name** by navigating to chrome://version from your chrome browser (You'll see Profile Path, but you only want the profile name from it (e.g. Profile 1)
2. Close out all Chrome sessions using the profile you want to use. (or else you will get the following error: InvalidArgumentException)
3. Now make sure you have the code below (Make sure you replace UserFolder with the name of your userfolder.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\EnterYourUserFolder\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") #leave out the profile
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1") #enter profile here
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've got the path to the profile right, and that you double escape backslashes in said path.

For example, typically the default profile on windows is located at:

`"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default"`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are meant to be putting in the webdriver path in the user-data-dir argument? That's usually where you put your chrome profile e.g. "C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\".  Also you will need to use either double backslashes or forward slashes in your directory path (both work). You can test if your path works by using the os library
e.g.

```
import os
os.list("C:\\Users\\yourusername\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1")
```

will give you the directory listing.

I might also add that occasionally if you manage to crash chrome while running webdriver with a nominated user profile, that it seems to record the crash in the profile and the next time you open chrome, you get the Chrome prompt to restore pages after it exited abnormally. For me personally this had been a bit of headache to deal with and I no longer use a user profile with chromedriver because of it. I could not find a way around it. Other people have reported it here, but none of their solutions seemed to work for me, or were not suitable for my test cases. https://superuser.com/questions/237608/how-to-hide-chrome-warning-after-crash
If you don't nominate a user profile it seems to create a new (blank) temporary one each time it runs

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me 100% and it showed up my selected profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to launch my chrome profile using these arguments:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 2");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

You can find out more about the web driver [here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/capabilities?authuser=0)

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to replace the `'\'` to `'/'` in your paths and that'll resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


# path of your chrome webdriver
dir_path = os.getcwd()
user_profile_path = os.environ[ 'USERPROFILE' ]

#if "frtkpr" which is ll be your custom profile does not exist it will be created.
option.add_argument( "user-data-dir=" + user_profile_path + "/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/frtkpr" )

driver = webdriver.Chrome( dir_path + "/chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=option )
baseUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get( baseUrl )
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing docker's remote driver profile path and using it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = Options()
#options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.jMPqvU/Default/") #Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://192.168.1.236:4444/wd/hub", options=options)
def print_profile():
    driver.get("chrome://version")
    profile=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]")
    print(profile.text)
print_profile()

#driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/45CxtJik/")
#print(driver.title)
```

Note: If the driver hangs there, it means the driver cannot find the path. For me, I wrote my path as
"/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.jMPqvU/Default"
And it hangs there, restart the docker container and try again with this path:
"/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.jMPqvU/Default/"

You need to add "/" symbol at the end.