# WebDriverError: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer(python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:/Users/ragha/Downloads/chromedriver_win32 (2)/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://google.com')

if driver.current_url!= 'https://google.com':
    driver.get('https://google.com')
```

**The chrome opens and then automatically crashes without opening the website.**

**Chrome Version**: 80.0.3987.122
**ChromeDriver Version**: 80.0.3987.106

[error on the terminal window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMYoV.png)

Comment: Please do not post errors as screenshots, but include them into your post. This will be easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: looks like chrome user profile issue. check these answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3