# Open new browser with existing session id

Tags: python, selenium

Suppose I have logged in a website using selenium python. If I open a new browser window then it is creating a new session , so in that window I need to re login to the website. My question is can I somehow use the existing session so that I don't need to re login to the website in that new window. Solution in python is preferable.

Comment: @Debanjan Try to understand the question first. He is asking related to the login session. Your pointing to selenium session.

Comment: @Navarasu Can you enlighten us about _selenium session_ and how it differs from _login session_ and how _Selenium_ deals with _login session_?

Comment: @Sounak Banerjee is the login session retained if you manually do the above steps? login, close and open browser again

Comment: @DebanjanB if the manual steps retain the session, then do u think this question is related to selenium browser session?

Comment: @Navarasu For once did you read the dupmarked discussion?

Comment: Yes, I read. It is completely unrelated to this question

Comment: @Navarasu Instead of beating around the bushes, can you care to explain, how?

Comment: @DebanjanB You should point this to your other answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3/52399027#52399027

Comment: @Navarasu You are a valued contributor too :)

Comment: @Navarasu no the login session is not retained even if I do it manually, you can think of gmail or facebook page as an example