# What is the correct directory for user-data-dir in Selenium chrome.options

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to do some chrome automation using selenium on python, and I want to have my login info saved for youtube, so that I don't have to automate the login process. I read that the way to have chrome read my saved info is by using the `user-data-dir` option, but I can't get it to work.

I have looked at some questions here, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3), and they seem to indicate that the correct usage of the argument `user-data-dir` in selenium for chrome is the profile path inside: `C:\Users\adassa\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`. Such as `Default` or `Profile 1`. I can't seem to get the intended result using this kind of path. The only path that works for me is the `User Data` folder itself.

So when I do:

`chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=" + r'C:\\Users\\adassa\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')`

The chrome instance is opened with the preferences set for the default profile. But that only works correctly when I close all other instances of chrome, otherwise it raises the error: `invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir`

Which I believe is caused by my manual chrome instance blocking access to the info on the folder because I'm using it. I read that I can create a new chrome profile, so that it doesn't conflict with the one I normally use, but if I create a new profile manually on chrome, and use the profile path, as in:

`chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=" + r'C:\\Users\\adassa\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1')`

the new instance doesn't have the info I saved to the profile. That happens even if I use as path the `User Data\Default` folder. I have also tried different combinations using the option `profile-dir`, with no success.

After reading the [docs](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities), I tried using a folder that does not exist. In that case selenium does create the new folder, but when I try to login to youtube trough that selenium created instance, in order to save the info for the browser to use on the next time, I get this message (translation mine):

> It was not possible to login. This browser or app may not be safe.

I would love to find a way to have my data saved so that I don't have to login everytime, and also not have to close all other chrome instances when running my script. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\adassa\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")
```

as the name says usr-dir is for user-data folder and profile-directory is to specify the  profile.

if profile folder is default , you don't have to specify that chrome takes it by default else specify it `"--profile-directory=Profile 1"`

Comment: For a moment I tought that I had just written `profile-directory` as `profile-dir`, but no, retested with `profile-directory`, it works for getting the Profile's info, but I still get the `user data directory is already in use` error

Comment: You have to copy the entire used dir folder to a new folder . And use that .

Comment: I see. That's unfortunate, the folder ends up being really big (almost 3GB), and even doing that, it doesn't allow me to open multiple instances of selenium using that info. Isn't there a way to open that info in a 'read only' way?

Comment: User data is to store information like cache cookies etc so can't be made read only