# How do I launch a browser with all the userdata(history, cookies & etc.) in python selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, browser, webdriver

How do I launch a browser with all the user data(history, cookies & etc.) in python selenium web driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load existing browser profile while opening a selenium web driver. For Chrome see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3), for FireFox see similar solutions