# Need help python open browser using specific profile

Tags: python, browser

Still new to a Python.
I need to be able to open a Chrome browser with specific profile.
And verify that proper the page is opened, by specific element on a page

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium to control the browser from python.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage

You can use the chrome driver that you download from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

You will use XPATH to locate the elements and validate the page
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Thanks, however, it is not exactly what i am looking for. I need to open browser with specific profile first

Comment: Have you tried this solution to include profiles? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).