# Is there any way to get text from an element on current browser in python?

Tags: python, html, web, browser, automation

the thing is I can login to the site only from one device, which is my browser so I can't use selenium, so I have to use something else which opens my browser and copy the text from an element using python.

Comment: you can use selenium, you just have to give it the original browser credentials.

Comment: something like `pyautogui` which just automates the keypresses and detect things on screen is viable for impossible to automate programs, but selenium is the correct library to use here.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: see the thing is i cant repeatedly login and log out and I want to completely automate it the site has captcha the site is [Site](https://digitalclass.allenoverseas.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may use one of two solutions:

1. use selenium to open a browser every time, and automate the login process.
2. If the site allows you to access without logging in when you access with your default browser(such as Stack Overflow for example - you don't need to login every time you open the website from your device),  you can use the same browser profile and it should do the same job - login automatically to that website.

references:

- [what's a browser profile?](https://blog.mozilla.org/en/products/firefox/profiles-shmofiles-whats-browser-profile-anyway/)
- [how to load a chrome's browser profile with python3 and selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3)

Comment: I cant site has captcha