# how to handle sign-in popups with python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Using selenium I need to handle this Chrome popup on a virtual machine, even when the remote desktop connection to it is closed.

[image]

I manage to get the credentials auto-filled by Chrome using my own user profile as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67389309/5224236).

Using pyautogui to press "enter" works when I am on the VM. The challenge is to make it work after I disconnect.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from datetime import datetime, date
import dateutil.relativedelta
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keyboard
import os
import pyautogui

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False # trying to keep sending keystrokes when remote desktop minimized or closed
chrome_driver = "path/to/exe"

# initial connection
rooturl = 'https://myurl'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data") 
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Default') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(rooturl)
windtitles = [x.title for x in pyautogui.getAllWindows()]
chromewindidx = [x for x, y  in enumerate(windtitles) if 'identityproviderinternal' in y][0]
chromewind = pyautogui.getAllWindows()[chromewindidx]
chromewind.minimize()
chromewind.maximize()
time.sleep(1)
if True:
  pyautogui.press('enter') # not working when I am not on the remote desktop
  time.sleep(15)
```

I also tried using `https://user:password@myurl` but it doesn't work on this particular system.

I also tried using `driver.switch_to.alert.accept()` which gives `NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert`

All solutions welcome but what I *think* I'd be after is some (`javascript`?) script to press this OK button using `driver.execute`, `driver.execute_script` or similar

Answer (score 0):

If it's an  element then you need to switch WebDriver to this frame in order to work with it. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
frames = wait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//iframe")))
frame = frames[0]
self.browser.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

The Xpath locator is just an example: *you need to write your own here*.

Also you can use any other locator to find that  element in the page source.

After switching to iframe element WebDriver will see it's page source and will be able to work with it.

Comment: it's not an element in the page, it's a popup rendered by the browser

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using `https://user:password@myurl` where `myurl` was the page where the popup appeared, not the final page I was trying to reach.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't seeing an alert window, it's a modal window, you'll have to refer to it by css id or class most likely.