# Can't see cookies ? But they exist

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I thought I knew how cookies work a little but I have doubts now.

1. Have a python3 script to run a web browser (Google Chrome, for instance) controlled by Selenium. With  `options.add_argument("user-data-dir=<folder_full_path>")` I set a folder for the browser folder. The folder does not exist yet.
2. Run the script. Read cookies with `driver.get_cookies()` and get an empty list obviously. Stop the script with `input()`
3. Manually visit www.dw.com; [www.paris.com](http://www.paris.com). Each greets me with a message and "have a cookie" button.
4. Read cookies with `driver.get_cookies()` again and can see cookies.
5. Quit the Selenium web browser and quit the Python script.

The Web browser folder is still there.

- Run the Python script again. `driver.get_cookies()` gives an empty list.
- Manually visit [www.dw.com](http://www.dw.com) and [www.paris.com](http://www.paris.com) They know me and I don't see any cookie messages (greetings).
- Stop Python script, and quit the selenium-driven web-browser.
  I erase (or rename) the web-browsers folder and repeat actions 1-5.

So, I realize that visited websites remember "me" but when I start a new web browser session I can not read their cookies even though I visited websites before but they exist somehow. Where? How can I read their cookies? Why dw.com and paris.com can see their cookies saved before but I can not?

Comment: Selenium by default enter Chrome as a Guest user. in order to log-in to your account you can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67389309/19574650

Comment: Thank you I.sh. I will study the link you gave. But how web-sites see their cookies and why can't I eventhough I'm a guest ? With chrome://version I took my user profile path which is "C:\Users\user_name_here\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default". It is pretty the same as "Default" folder in <folder_full_path> mentioned above. What is the difference ? What if I set in '--profile-directory=...' "Default" folder from <folder_full_path> ?

Comment: Have you tried using incognito mode of your browser? Always worked for me

Comment: @Knight I don't know. What is it when I use Selenium ? How can It help ?

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/40777  This answer should help

Comment: @Knight It did not help. According to written there I have to see cookies invitation every time I visit the website but it does not happen as I wrote before. I see accept cookie button just once. Websites know me but I can see their cookies just once when I visit them for the first time. When I restart my script I can not see their cookies anymore but websites know that I visited them before. That is the question.